# Wrong answer when multiplying variables

Tags: java, math

I'm trying to multiply two variables. One is an int and the other is inside a char array.

My code is this

```
int biggestProduct = 1;
int currProduct = 1;
char[] array = num.toCharArray();

for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
    if (x < 5) {
        System.out.println(currProduct + " * " + array[x] + " = " + currProduct * array[x]);
        currProduct *= array[x];
    }
}

return biggestProduct;
```

The problem is with the `currProduct*= array[x]`

This is my output when I print it out:

```
1 * 7 = 55
55 * 3 = 2805
2805 * 1 = 137445
137445 * 6 = 7422030
7422030 * 7 = 408211650
```

Why isn't it multiplying correctly?

Comment: I have a feeling '7''s numeric value isn't 7

Comment: Why is it not correct? What do you expect the result of `1*'z'`to be, for example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the numeric value of the `char` `7` is not `7` but `55`.

Because in Java, the char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character (see encoding table below).

[image]

If you take a look at this table, you see that 7 is encoded as `0x0037 = 3*16^1 + 7 = 55`.

If you want to take the real numeric value of your character, you can use [`Character.getNumericValue(char ch)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue%28char%29) :

```
 char ch = '7';
 int number = Character.getNumericValue(ch);
 System.out.print(number); //print 7
```

So to edit your code, it will looks like :

```
        String num = "73167";
        int biggestProduct = 1;
        int currProduct = 1;
        char[] array = num.toCharArray();

        for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
            if (x < 5) {
                System.out.println(currProduct + " * " + array[x] + " = " + currProduct * Character.getNumericValue(array[x]));
                currProduct *= Character.getNumericValue(array[x]);
            }

        }
```

Output :

```
1 * 7 = 7
7 * 3 = 21
21 * 1 = 21
21 * 6 = 126
126 * 7 = 882
```

Verification : `7*3*1*6*7 = 882`

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
currProduct *= (int) array[x];
```

Check [here](http://www.asciitable.com/) for what the char values usually represent. You will see that if you want your char to hold the numerical value 2, you have to actually assign 50:

```
char two = 50;
System.out.println(two); // prints out 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of '7' is 55 because it is just another character like e.g. 'a', so its numeric value will be its ASCII code. See here: http://www.asciitable.com/
(Note that the used ASCII table can be also implementation dependant.)

Answer (score 1):

The numeric value of '7' isn't 7, it's 55. This is like any character, for example the character 'A' is 65

For example

```
public class Calendar
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        char testChar='7';
        int testInt=testChar;

        System.out.println(testInt); //prints 55
    }
}
```